# az ad app permission grant 403 Forbidden for url

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am encountering an error executing the `az ad app permission grant` command via local terminal.

Do you need to be a Global administrator to be able to execute command? I am getting 403 Forbidden for url error, even though I can exactly do the same in the Portal manually. I am set as the owner for both App Registrations.

`clientID = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"`

`$apiID= 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx`

`az ad app permission grant --api $apiId --id $clientID --scope user_impersonation`

Operation failed with status: 'Forbidden'. Details: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.windows.net/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2PermissionGrants?api-version=1.6

Comment: Yes `you must login as a global administrator` to execute this command, as `owner role` is not allow for this execution. You could [`check here in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: Thank you, do you mean that all commands for `az ad app permission` can only be executed by a Global administrator? That is odd because the same can be done in the Portal manually, and then it limits automating the task. From the documentation, it mentioned only on `az ad app permission admin-consent` requires to be logged in as Global administrator

Comment: Yes right you are, but using `Powershell` and `CLI` you should have that permission, you can get that on the document I have shared. Let me know if you need any further assistance on it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - the documentation lacked clarity that **all** commands for `az ad app permission` executed using `powershell` and `cli` can only be performed by a user with a global administrator role.

Comment: I have added an answer if that if helpful you can accept it. You can do that by right clicking on left check mark beside your question [you could have a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)